# Ubuntu not showing in grub menu after dual booting with Arch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, grub

Earlier my laptop had only Ubuntu on `/dev/sda5` and it's swap memory on `/dev/sda6` in which I logged in through grub menu. I installed Arch on `/dev/sda1` and it's swap memory on `/dev/sda2` and again installed grub menu. Now when booting my laptop, I only see Arch Linux in grub menu. What should I do so that Ubuntu also shows in grub menu? I tried making my `/dev/sda5` as "Bootable" in `cfdisk` but that didn't help.

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN     RM   SIZE    RO TYPE     MOUNTPOINT
sda          8:0         0   238.5G  0  disk
├─sda1       8:1         0   194.5M  0  part     /
├─sda2       8:2         0       4M  0  part    [SWAP]
├─sda4       8:4         0       1K  0  part
├─sda5       8:5         0    36.2G  0  part
`─sda6       8:6         0     3.8G  0  part
```

Commands executed while installation for `grub`:

```bsh
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `os-prober` then mount Ubuntu partition:

> [Detecting other operating systems](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Detecting_other_operating_systems)
>
> To have grub-mkconfig search for other installed systems and automatically add them to the menu, install the os-prober package and mount the partitions that contain the other systems. Then re-run grub-mkconfig.

Or add Ubuntu the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` :

[Dual-booting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Dual-booting)

> Assuming that the other distribution is on partition sda2:
>
> ```
> menuentry "Other Linux" {
>     set root=(hd0,2) #  In your case : set root=(hd0,5)
>     linux /boot/vmlinuz # (add other options here as required)
>     initrd /boot/initrd.img # (if the other kernel uses/needs one)
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Just mounting Ubuntu by `mount /dev/sda5 /mnt` and running `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` helped. :)

Comment: Yes, for me it found Ubuntu when I mounted it. Thanks